# How do I use Material UI theme colors inside a div?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I made a library that uses some Material UI components and they adapt their colors according to the theme provided by the project that installs them. I also want to use the "primary", "secondary" colors on a div because I want the background-color to adapt to the theme as well. Is there a way to do that?

In a Button the only thing I need to do is

```
<Button color="secondary"/>
```

But how do I do the equivalent to a div as well?

```
const MainContainer = styled.div`
      background: secondary;
    `;
```

How do I make this secondary color be the color of the theme of the parent project, like in the button?

Comment: You can explicitly set it to the color value; divs don't have a "secondary" color like that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have any prior experience with `style compononent`. But as for `materail-ui`, you can apply `color` in **2 ways**:-

1. using `useTheme` (inline use only - as far as I know), imported from `material-ui/core/styles`:-

```js
import { useTheme } from 'material-ui/core/styles'

export const Demo = () => {
  const theme = useTheme()

  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main }}>Hi You!</div>  
  )
}
```

2. using `makeStyles` (you can solely use this without `styled-component`), imported from `material-ui/core/styles`

```js
import { makeStyles } from 'material-ui/core/styles'

export const Demo = () => {
  const classes = useStyles()

  return (
    <div className={classes.divStyle}>Hi You!</div>  
  )
}

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  divStyle: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main
    // or any color
    // backgroundColor: 'red'
  }
}))
```

Comment: Great! Glad able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You could get access to the colors which are present in the **theme** object by using useTheme hook.

https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#usetheme-theme